# "I like things done once"

Tags: cipher, computer-puzzle

You disable the security shields. Dr P releases his minions. Suddenly you hear the red siren.

'Code-Red' says the computer. You smell smoke. You see the background a blur and noises in the air. Your passing out. It seems you are dead............

You bang your head into the nearby wall. "This is surely the most secure encryption I've ever seen" mumbling to yourself.  Your acquaintance surely knows what to do. He clicks one button and clicks some more. "All isn't lost" he announces. "We were able to intercept some text after all. But I seriously doubt if this even makes sense."

You jump up at the remarkable accomplishment. You see the text. You smile. You say "Too much of anything is bad. It seems Dr P is indeed lazy."

2d0b020639280918570b262b5f581e6c36036b10302d401e5c43330a304629471a184337441d0e13
0e31171c0335080c590b26345248325e3002513b2b1a52186c5b02103a6c15521c26550d6e080609
08023c15080e240440311a3e596e1f5629155508000b5c03416b1f163c4113472d18590c6e02021c
1f0b3c0d091f241e411c092d5e420857003f5a0100265a1b566b3c123b6c1f402d0f42045f0b151c
0b02062b1205241e410d1100564519523c1b473b0f005600565a182c3647295d1701433745070a18

> Suddenly the computer screen flashes; "Greetings Mr O and Mr T, I see you intercepted some of our messages. But 'ha' you intercepted garbage. The real key is with me; with which I can open all the doors. Better luck next time, if you have one."

> You laugh. You give a sudden stare to Dr P "It's quite funny. If all the doors can be opened with one key, then I won't necessarily call it secure."

> The computer screen starts pixelating. Some weird lines appear. You see the lines closely. Your acquaintance sees something weird. "It's strange how all the lines are so similar in size even though they seem so random" says Mr O. Suddenly, the monitor flashes again and turns off.
>  The computer screen broke. "We'll have to call in 'Frank Miller' to take a look at this. Maybe we'll have to buy a new one this time".

> The computer screen turns back on again. You see some more garbage text.  "JungUnccrafVsVCynprZrGuraLbhNaqGuraQeCVaNYvar FnlfGurNffvfgnag"

> Somebody below definitely knows what to do.

Comment: Frank Miller is a creator of OTP, also i think title indicates it's OTP... but i might be wrong

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

The last garbage code means:

> whathappensifiplacemethenyouandthendrpinalinesaystheassistant 
>  with a 13 caesar cipher

or well formatted:

> What happens if I place me then you and then dr p in a line says the assistant

So

> So we probably need 3 names to make a key. Or it may be just a clue for OTP cipher.

Also:

> all the lines in the hexa are 40 bytes long. It might be the size of the key.

Comment: I should have missed it. I can't figure out how to get text input from the hexa.

Answer (score 1):

This is a puzzle from the [InCTF Jr](https://junior.inctf.in/) competition from several years ago. The flag is:

> ```
> inctfj{m4ny_71m3_p4d_r3v34ls_3v3ry7h1ng}
> ```

I can't seem to find this puzzle among [the published solutions from 2018](https://github.com/teambi0s/InCTFj).